# What is removing files under /tmp on an ~hourly basis?

Tags: trash, tmp

On the timescale of one hour, something is removing files that I create in `/tmp`.

What removes the files?  Alternatively, how might I find out?

My `/etc/cron.hourly` directory is empty except for a file named `.placeholder` whose contents are simply:

```
# DO NOT EDIT OR REMOVE
# This file is a simple placeholder to keep dpkg from removing this directory
```

In Settings -> Privacy in `gnome-control-center`, in "Purge Rubbish Bin contents & Temporary Files" both toggles are set off (incidentally I'm British and living in the UK but in this context it makes me laugh to hear it described as a "Rubbish Bin" instead of "Trash"!).

Comment: I figured out that I'm removing the files myself in my per-user crontab (`crontab -l` showed me my mistake)!  Oops.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no information what OS/Version you are using, my best bet would be

```
systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer - Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
```